# Is there jQuery plugin for editing text similar to Google plus posting box - using contenteditable?

Tags: jquery, contenteditable, google-plus

I am currently searching up and down for jQuery plugin that would be similar to the box for posting text on Google Plus. It uses contenteditable="plaintext-only" and is very simple to use, especially when some external content (link, image, video, ...) is mentioned in the text.

Is there something at least close to appearance and function to Google+'s contenteditable textbox ?

Answer (score 1):

No, Google's editor is custom.  It also requires an additional server component that goes out and fetches the external content and formats it to display nicely in the editor.

The closest you'll get is a rich text editor like [TinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com/).  However, this is only intended for [WYSIWYG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WYSIWYG) editing, and doesn't have any facilities for fetching and formatting external content when links are posted.

Comment: Soviut: I wouldn't mind using server component you are mentioning. TinyMCE is overkill for me, I would rather like to use something very simple but functional as Google+ post box...

Comment: TinyMCE can be configured to be much simpler, but it's your best hope at actually integrating fetched data (such as youtube links, tweets, images, links, etc.) and gives you WYSIWYG editing out of the box.  Remember, the simpler something looks, the more effort it required to build.

Comment: Also, those server components are proprietary; Google wrote them specifically for Google+.